# UI_project.h not found for QT project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I made a QT GUI project in VS 2019. It ran perfectly through VS. Copied the entire project files directory to Linux partition. Ran qmake -project in the directory containing the 'test2.sln' file to create a 'test2.pro' file. Opened the '*.pro' file through QT Creator. It imported everything fine. But, when building it it errors out saying "ui_test2.h file not found".

The test2.pro contains:

```
TEMPLATE = app

TARGET = test2
INCLUDEPATH += .

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

HEADERS += test2/test2.h test2/x64/Release/uic/ui_test2.h

FORMS += test2/test2.ui

SOURCES += test2/main.cpp test2/test2.cpp test2/x64/Release/rcc/qrc_test2.cpp

RESOURCES += test2/test2.qrc
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild not build it?

Comment: Yes, Rebuilding results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1) remove folder with build (`rm -r nameOfFolder`)

2) rename your UI file (test2.ui -> mainwindow.ui) for example

3) check out name of own class and name of qt class in UI file (you can open it via vim or nano)

After that try to rebuild your project! 
I hope you'll have done this with good results!

Comment: It didn't work. I removed the build file. Renamed the *.ui file into mainwindow.ui. QT creator displayed a pop up to rename other files as well. Clicking No just caused more errors. I clicked Yes to rename. Changed the classes used in mainwindow.ui using kate and also changed all the used class names in all the files. Most errors disappeared except one which in mainwindow.h highlighted Ui in Ui::mainwindowClass ui; rebuilding this caused the same error as before.